Dynamic Distance between Instances while rotate
I have the following problem:
I have created a simple grid to which an Instances on Points node is connected.
I used an Object Info Node for the instances. However, the object is larger in width than in length. So it is misshapen. I set the distance between the instances via the grid size - so that the instances do not touch each other.
If I now rotate the instances, there will be overlaps and this is exactly what I want to avoid.
I am looking for a solution where the instances are dynamically at the same distance. No matter how they are rotated. Does anyone have an idea how I can implement this?
In the first picture you can see the project overview.
The second picture shows the structure and the desired distance between the instances.
In the third picture you can see the problem (clipping).
On the fourth picture you can see how it should look like.
I have adjusted it manually via the grid size. But an automated process would be best.
PS: I am aware that I can use the Poisson Disk via the Distribute on Faces Node. There I can determine the instance between the instances or points. However, the distance is always the same. But I want the instances to have a dynamic distance to each other... like with a Geometry Proximity Node...





i hope this is what you wanted:
with this node tree:

you will get this:
https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/grid%20packed.gif
Link here instead of pasting directly because adding gifs seems still to be buggy on this site.
Hope this helps.

Hey Chris,
thank you for your answer. It was a great help. Many thanks!
The only problem is: I don't understand the node tree :D
I'll try to understand it piece by piece...
Anyway: Thanks a lot - problem solved!

Sorry but I have another question.
I have been experimenting with your node tree for some time now and in principle everything works perfectly.
However, I wonder if you can move the origin point.
Currently, the dynamic distance from the bottom left corner extends to the top right. What could a solution look like where the stretching happens from the center?
If you could help again, I would be very grateful :-)

@fefe: please ask a new question for this. You may open as many questions as you like. Why? in the comments nobody can find your questions or answer in the comments, so everybody who is interested in it, can find your question and the answer as well. Thank you for your understanding.

Okay, I understand. I'm still new here on Stack Exchange so I don't quite understand the process. I thought the question was very specific to your node tree, that's why I put it as a comment. Opening a fundamentally new question would probably be a bit messy.
